# Stacks management by operating system

Tags: multithreading, memory-management, operating-system

I am an absolute beginner in operating systems. So please, do not mind if the question appears too naive or basic.
From what I've read, each process has its own Kernel stack and User stack. So does each thread. Threads of a process share the same address space. They also share the code and data segment, but not the stack. 
But how is this possible? There is only one stack pointer in a CPU, so how can each thread have its own stack? 
And what is the difference b/w stack and stack frame? From what I've read, there is only one stack and frames are pushed on it. Again, it is a physical stack? Do these stack exist in the virtual memory? Can someone please clear my concepts? I am confused and cannot move forward.

Comment: Every thread has its own set of processor registers.  Switching the processor from one thread to another takes swapping the registers.  The stack pointer is part of it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

Comment: This may help https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/l06.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> From what I've read, each process has its own Kernel stack and User stack. So does each thread.

Each thread has its own kernel and user stack. Processes may contain any number of stacks -- at least one for each of their threads, possibly more.

> Threads of a process share the same address space. They also share the code and data segment, but not the stack. But how is this possible?

Because the term "share" is being used in two different ways.

My wife and I both jointly own two cars, so in that sense, we share two cars. But I have one car that only I use and she has one car that only she uses. In that sense, we each have our own car.

Similarly, a process with two threads has two stacks that are shared. One is for each thread. So each thread has its own stack, though they can access each other's stacks if they wish to.

> There is only one stack pointer in a CPU, so how can each thread have its own stack?

A stack can be sitting on disk. A stack can be sitting in memory but not being used as a stack.

> And what is the difference b/w stack and stack frame? From what I've read, there is only one stack and frames are pushed on it.

Right, so a single stack could have several frames pushed onto it. When one function finishes, it pops of its stack frame and returns to the caller with the caller's frame on the top of the stack.

> Again, it is a physical stack?

I don't know what that means.

> Do these stack exist in the virtual memory?

Yes. That's why one thread can easily access variables on another thread's stack if the address is passed from one to the other. A stack is just some memory that's being used as a stack.

Comment: If each thread can access the other's stack and vice-versa, wouldn't it be kind of a screwed-up situation? I mean, what if a thread begins writing into the other thread's stack? Is there any protection of some kind?

Comment: @PrashantPandey The whole point of threads is that they can easily access shared memory. It's perfectly normal for threads to read from or write to each other's stacks. If you don't think you can make that work sensibly, either don't do it or don't use threads. The protection is a programmer who knows what they're doing.

Comment: For example, one thread might construct some objects that need work on its stack, then launch a pool of threads to work on those objects, wait for the threads to finish working, and then look at the results in those objects. There's no problem with this if locks are used properly. Threads must cooperate.

Comment: Got it. Thanks man. I need to work a lot on my fundamentals I think. Can you help me with any tips? I mean, a suggesting a book or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, all the good books I know of are at least a decade old.